# Extension of essential singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, summation, singularity

I need to proof that if a function $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_{0}$ then can be expressed as a sum of the form:

$f(z)=\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^n$

I really don't have idea how to do this problem.

Comment: If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on the annulus $a < |z| < b$ then so is $f(z) z^{-n}$ so you can use the Cauchy integral theorem
$$\int_{|z| = r} f(z)z^{-n} dz - \int_{|z| = R} f(z)z^{-n} dz = 0, \qquad a < r < R < b$$ to obtain
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n, \qquad a_n = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|z| = r} f(z)z^{-n} dz, \qquad a < r  < b$$

Comment: Is 0 because the two functions have the same singularities out the annulus, right?

Comment: You should look at the Cauchy integral theorem in the case of an annulus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More precisely, if $f$ has an essential singularity at $z=z_0$, then $f$ is expressed as a Laurent series around $z_0$:
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n,
$$
with infinitely many non-vanishing terms with negative index.

**Fact I.** If $f$ is analytic in $A=\{z\in\mathbb C: 0<|z-z_0|<r\}$, then $f$ can be expressed as a Laurent series around $z_0$:
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n,
$$
which converges (locally uniformly) for every $z\in A$.

**Fact II.** If $f$ is analytic in $A=\{z\in\mathbb C: 0<|z-z_0|<r\}$, and $z_0$ is a removable singularity then $a_n=0$, for all $n<0$. If $z_0$ is a pole, then there exists a $k\in\mathbb N$, such that $a_n=0$, wherever $-n>k$ - $k$ is the degree of the pole. Finally, if $z_0$ is an essential singularity, then $a_n\ne 0$, for infinitely many negative $n$'s.

Comment: Do you know any source with a proof of the facts?

Comment: I am currently teaching Complex Analysis following the textbook of Bak and Newman. Isolated singularities are covered in pages 117-125.